# How can I profile bazel's disk usage?

Tags: profiling, bazel

Bazel has some decent built-in profiling for both CPU and RAM use: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/performance.html

But I haven't been able to find anything that would let me profile how much *disk space* rules use up as they run.

Is there a way?  If not, is there somewhere that I might I need to modify bazel in order to collect this information?